# Работа двух слайдеров отдельно друг от друга

Tags: html, jquery, слайдер

На странице есть два слайдера и один код на оба сладера.
Как "заставить" их работать отдельно друг от друга используя один и тот же код?

p.s. Без изменения `html`

```js
$('.slider .slider-button').on('click', function() {
    var buttonPrev = $(this).hasClass('prev'),
      buttonNext = $(this).hasClass('next'),
      slideBlock = $('.slider-content .slider-slide'),
      slideActive = $('.slider-content .slider-slide.active'),
      slideLen = slideBlock.length,
      slideActiveIndex = slideActive.index(),
      slidePrev = (slideActiveIndex - 1),
      slideNext = (slideActiveIndex + 1),
      isEvents = $(this).hasClass('-events');
    slideBlock.removeClass('active');
    if (isEvents) {
      var catBlock = $('.slide-title.plus-cat .category .cat-item'),
        catActive = $('.slide-title.plus-cat .category .cat-item.active'),
        catLen = slideBlock.length,
        catActiveIndex = slideActive.index(),
        catPrev = (slideActiveIndex - 1),
        catNext = (slideActiveIndex + 1);
      catBlock.removeClass('active');
    }
    if (buttonPrev) {
      slideBlock.eq(slidePrev).addClass('active');
      if (isEvents) catBlock.eq(catPrev).addClass('active');
    }
    if (buttonNext) {
      if (slideNext == slideLen) var slideNext = 0;
      slideBlock.eq(slideNext).addClass('active');
      if (isEvents) {
        if (catNext == catLen) var catNext = 0;
        catBlock.eq(catNext).addClass('active');
      }
    }
  }

);
```

```css
.slider {display: grid; grid-template-columns: 50px 1fr 50px; grid-gap: 10px; height: 200px; margin-bottom: 20px;}
.slider .slider-button, .slider .slider-content {display: block; width: 100%;}
.slider .slider-button {position: relative; cursor: pointer;}
.slider .slider-button div {width: 50px; height: 50px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: auto 100%; background-position: center center; position: absolute; top: calc(50% - 25px);}
.slider .slider-button.prev div {background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50x50');}
.slider .slider-button.next div {background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50x50');}
.slider .slider-content {overflow: hidden;}
.slider .slider-content .slider-slide {display: none; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
.slider .slider-content .slider-slide img {display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: contain;}
.slider .slider-content .slider-slide.active {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Первый слайдер -->
<div class="slider about">
  <div class="slider-button prev">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-content">
    <div class="slider-slide active" style="background: red;"></div>
    <div class="slider-slide" style="background: blue;"></div>
    <div class="slider-slide" style="background: green;"></div>
    <div class="slider-slide" style="background: yellow;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-button next">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Второй слайдер -->

<div class="slider events">
  <div class="slider-button prev -events">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-content">
    <div class="slider-slide active" style="background: black;"></div>
    <div class="slider-slide" style="background: aqua;"></div>
    <div class="slider-slide" style="background: brown;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-button next -events">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Опишу только общий подход. В `$('.slider .slider-button').on('click' ...` вы должны сначала найти элемент `.slider`, а затем у него найти ребёнка `.slider-content`. И уже для последнего выполнять переключение элементов. Лучше такие вещи выносить в отдельный компонент. Должно получаться что-то вроде `$(selector).slide({})`

Comment: @ArchDemon, т.е. нужно для `.slider-content` дописать какой-то идентификатор, правильно понимаю?  
И как быть с переменными?

Comment: Вам поможет вот [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) и [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/) (на всякий случай вот [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так?

```js
$('.slider .slider-button').on('click', function(e) {

    var slides = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[3];

    var buttonPrev = $(this).hasClass('prev'),
      buttonNext = $(this).hasClass('next'),
      slideBlock = jQuery(slides.getElementsByClassName('slider-slide')),
      slideActive = jQuery(slides.querySelector('.active')),
      slideLen = slideBlock.length,
      slideActiveIndex = slideActive.index(),
      slidePrev = (slideActiveIndex - 1),
      slideNext = (slideActiveIndex + 1),
      isEvents = $(this).hasClass('-events');
    slideBlock.removeClass('active');
    if (isEvents) {
      var catBlock = $('.slide-title.plus-cat .category .cat-item'),
        catActive = $('.slide-title.plus-cat .category .cat-item.active'),
        catLen = slideBlock.length,
        catActiveIndex = slideActive.index(),
        catPrev = (slideActiveIndex - 1),
        catNext = (slideActiveIndex + 1);
      catBlock.removeClass('active');
    }
    if (buttonPrev) {
      slideBlock.eq(slidePrev).addClass('active');
      if (isEvents) catBlock.eq(catPrev).addClass('active');
    }
    if (buttonNext) {
      if (slideNext == slideLen) var slideNext = 0;
      slideBlock.eq(slideNext).addClass('active');
      if (isEvents) {
        if (catNext == catLen) var catNext = 0;
        catBlock.eq(catNext).addClass('active');
      }
    }
  }

);
```

```css
.slider {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 1fr 50px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.slider .slider-button,
.slider .slider-content {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.slider .slider-button {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider .slider-button div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 25px);
}

.slider .slider-button.prev div {
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50x50');
}

.slider .slider-button.next div {
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50x50');
}

.slider .slider-content {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider .slider-content .slider-slide {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slider .slider-content .slider-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.slider .slider-content .slider-slide.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Первый слайдер -->
<div class="slider about">
  <div class="slider-button prev">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-content">
    <div class="slider-slide active" style="background: red;"></div>
    <div class="slider-slide" style="background: blue;"></div>
    <div class="slider-slide" style="background: green;"></div>
    <div class="slider-slide" style="background: yellow;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-button next">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Второй слайдер -->

<div class="slider events">
  <div class="slider-button prev -events">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-content">
    <div class="slider-slide active" style="background: black;"></div>
    <div class="slider-slide" style="background: aqua;"></div>
    <div class="slider-slide" style="background: brown;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-button next -events">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Всё же рекомендовал использовать функции jquery `parent(selector)` и `find(selector)`. В случае смены внутренней структуры слайдера, код не поломается. Но данный вариант, конечно, быстрее.

Comment: @ya.ymer, да, спасибо) Но я только что решил проблему сам, заменив `slideBlock = $('.slider-content .slider-slide'), slideActive = $('.slider-content .slider-slide.active')` на `slideBlock = $(this).closest('.slider').find('.slider-slide'), slideActive = $(this).closest('.slider').find('.slider-slide.active')`. Отмечу Ваш ответ как правильный)

Comment: @ArchDemon привык к ванилле, извиняйте. ;)